# AutoComboBox DisplayMemberPath call Converter or Set MultiBinding

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox

In ComboBox ItemSource List Class set one Property that is Object of the class and I have to set in one for display purpose when I selectedItem

```
    <AutoComboBox x:Name="cbPatient" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Patients}"
                         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPatient}">
        <AutoComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name,Converter={StaticResource NameToFullNameConverter}}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </control:AutoComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <control:AutoComboBox.DropDownView>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Type" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name,Converter={StaticResource NameToFullNameConverter}}"/>
                </GridView>
            </control:AutoComboBox.DropDownView>
        </control:AutoComboBox>
```

this converter works in DropDownView, but not work when I select an item from DropDownView
Thanks in advance